# Scala Double save and read from a binary file deterministically

Tags: scala, file, binary, double, precision

How can I make Scala save Double to a binary file and read it back with *no loss* of precision?

Scala already has a good framework for saving Double to a text file, encoded as a String representation in base 10.   However, doing so introduces roundoff error. The conversion of **IEEE 754 64-bit floating** point to decimal is imperfect and introduces slight roundoff error.  A simulation that is "backed up" to disk every two hours and then reloaded from disk and resumed would not be deterministic. The simulation that was left running would differ from the one that was paused and resumed from a file. Your thoughts?

Comment: Could you use an arbitrary precision format like BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I think you should use `BigDecimal`

### Precautions

- The `BigDecimal(String)` constructor should always be preferred over `BigDecimal(Double)` because using `BigDecimal(double)` is unpredictable due to the inability of the double to represent 0.1 as exact 0.1.
- If double must be used for initializing a `BigDecimal`, use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, which converts the `Double` value to String using `Double.toString(double)` method
- Rounding mode should be provided while setting the scale
- `StripTrailingZeros` chops off all the trailing zeros
- `toString()` may use scientific notation but, `toPlainString()` will never return exponentiation in its result

Refer to this link:

https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio

Answer (score 0):

You can save decimals in binary format as-is byte-by-byte:

```
val fos: OutputStream = ???
val out = new DataOutputStream(fos)
out.writeDouble(1.0)
```

Comment: This DataOutputStream what I was looking for.   I will post an example at the bottom. Thanks for your answer to this question.

Comment: @KseniaSemenova you are welcome! If an answer solves your problem, you should accept and upvote it rather than rewrite under your name with minor corrections. I'm not hunting for reputation, just clarifying how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Following simpadjo 's suggestion ,

```
val sn:List[Double] = List(
          -4.2745321334280,-0.8827640054242,
          0.5781790299989,-2.5173973937094,
          4.3955017758756);
val outputstm:OutputStream = new FileOutputStream( "numbers.bin" )
val dos:DataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputstm)
for( k <- sn ) dos.writeDouble(k)
dos.close()
outputstm.close()
```